# How to manage postgresql foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-structures

I need some advice on SQL structure on Postgresql.

I have those two tables :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."attribute_value";

CREATE TABLE "public"."attribute_value"
(
"id"                        INTEGER NOT NULL,
"attribute_id"              INTEGER NOT NULL,
"value"                     CHARACTER VARYING(100) NULL

);

--*****************************************************

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."product_attribute";

CREATE TABLE "public"."product_attribute"
(
"product_id"                INTEGER NOT NULL,
"attribute_value_id"        INTEGER NOT NULL,
"attribute_id"              INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

I added no constraints on purpose.
I need a foreign key on the child table product_attribute.attribute_value_id referencing the parent table attribute_value.id. The best practice is to create a primary key on the field attribute_value.id  (maybe with a sequence), or to CREATE UNIQUE INDEX on attribute_value.id ?
I first thought indexes were only special lookup tables that the database search engine can use to speed up data retrieval. But when I played with foreign keys, I found that creating an unique index allowed me to avoid error "there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table blablabla" because a foreign key is not supposed to point to a non unique value. Should indexes be used to create foreign keys then  ?

I also need a foreign key on the child table product_attribute.attribute_id referencing parent table attribute_value.attribute_id. The problem is that attribute_value.attribute_id is not unique. But all the rows in product_attribute.attribute_id must not take any value out of attribute_value.attribute_id's possible values. How should I do ?

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to accomplish. At best the data model you have laid out is very poor. Also a little research/study on foreign keys and referential integrity.  Further "foreign key is not supposed to point to a non unique value" is not quite correct. That must read "**foreign key *cannot* point to a non unique value**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every table should have a primary key. Don't join the legion of people who complain about duplicate rows in their tables.

So make `id` the primary key of `attribute_value`, then you can create a foreign key constraint.

Constraints are implemented by unique indexes, so technically they are almost the same. Still you need a constraint and not just a unique index as the target of a foreign key constraint.

About `attribute_id`: that should not be a foreign key constraint between the two tables from your question, but both tables should have a foreign key referencing yet another table (`attribute`?).